# There is no bug in those two jQuery statements but I am just wondering why

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

The following work perfectly

```
sendtext5 = "Homer Simpson";

$eraser.prop('value', sendtext5);

$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer( "change", $article2 );
```

But not the following

```
sendtext5 = "Homer Simpson";

$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer( "change", $article2 );  // This line executes

$eraser.prop('value', sendtext5);   // This line does not execute
```

$article2 is a div tag and $eraser is an input tag.

I am wondering why the second situation works but the first does.

It is jQuery 2.1.1 and jQuery Mobile 1.4.5

Thanks a lot, Stack Overflow!

Comment: Add `console.log($article2)` and `console.log($eraser)` tell us exactly what it prints out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that `$eraser` is an element within `$article2`.  If it's not, then this answer is probably worthless.

In the first example, you are setting the property BEFORE JQM enhances the layout.

In the second example, you are setting it AFTER the layout is enhanced.  This means that you are changing the `value` property, but on the underlying form element.  You need to tell JQM to re-render the displayed element.

If `$eraser` is a text box, then try the following:

```
sendtext5 = "Homer Simpson";
$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer( "change", $article2 ); // This line executes
$eraser.prop('value', sendtext5);   // This line does execute, just on the underlying element
$eraser.textinput( "refresh" ); // This line refreshes the displayed element with the underlying elements's properties
```